# Search Filtering with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a search/filtering option in my blood donor application. Where donor can be searched by sex, name, blood group or by selecting all three. Here is my code

```
function search_donar($_POST) {

        $by_name = $_POST['by_name'];
        $by_sex = $_POST['by_sex'];
        $by_group = $_POST['by_group'];
        $by_level = $_POST['by_level'];

        $search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar WHERE";
        if($by_name !="") {
          $search_query .= " name='$by_name'";
        }
        if($by_sex !="") {
          $search_query .= " sex='$by_sex'";
        }
        if($by_group !="") {
          $search_query .= " blood_group='$by_group'";
        }
        if($by_level !="") {
          $search_query .= " e_level='$by_level'";
        }
        $search_query;
        $result = mysql_query($search_query);

        return $result;
    }
```

And here is the html

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $retrived_result = $donar->search_donar($_POST);

}

   <form action="" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0" style="border:none;">
      <tr>
        <td><label>Name:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="by_name" /></td>
        <td><label>Sex:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="by_sex" /></td>
        <td><label>Blood Group:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="by_group" /></td>
        <td><label>Level:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="by_level" /></td>
        <td><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Single filtering works very fine. But To filter with all I used AND , but it gives me error. Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error does it give you...?

Comment: Please at least escape your data while searching in database with `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['by_name']);` It is strongly recommended that use mysqli_* or PDO instead of mysql_*

Comment: What is `$donar` variable in your question?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like all the other post you will need to append all the conditions with AND like so. This is the cleanest answer so far. Remember to real escape your strings though use the mysqli OOP way instead of the old mysql. Just a suggestion.

Heres an example of a typical query.

The correct way:

```
SELECT * FROM donar WHERE name='dxenaretionx' AND sex='M';
```

The way you are doing it

```
SELECT * FROM donar WHERE name='dxenaretionx' sex='M';
```

Code:

```
function search_donar($_POST) {
    $by_name = $_POST['by_name'];
    $by_sex = $_POST['by_sex'];
    $by_group = $_POST['by_group'];
    $by_level = $_POST['by_level'];

    //Do real escaping here

    $query = "SELECT * FROM donar";
    $conditions = array();

    if(! empty($by_name)) {
      $conditions[] = "name='$by_name'";
    }
    if(! empty($by_sex)) {
      $conditions[] = "sex='$by_sex'";
    }
    if(! empty($by_group)) {
      $conditions[] = "blood_group='$by_group'";
    }
    if(! empty($by_level)) {
      $conditions[] = "e_level='$by_level'";
    }

    $sql = $query;
    if (count($conditions) > 0) {
      $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
    }

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: One of the best and clear answers I have seen on stackoverflow. Thank you very much @Rejinderi.

Comment: thank you @LaurenceNicolaou your comment made my day :D

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet:

```
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar WHERE";
if($by_name !="") {
  $search_query .= " name='$by_name'";
}
if($by_sex !="") {
  $search_query .= " sex='$by_sex'";
}
```

produces queries like

```
SELECT * FROM donar WHERE name='nowak' sex='m'
```

, which are not valid because there is no logical operator between the clauses. You need to add an 'AND'. To simplify code, you can generate conditions in the form of "true and a and b ...":

```
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar WHERE true";
if($by_name !="") {
  $search_query .= " AND name='$by_name'";
}
if($by_sex !="") {
  $search_query .= " AND sex='$by_sex'";
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

There in Your code there is problem in query where condition . Here your query will be like 
`select * from donar where by_name = "A" by_group = "N"` there is No `And/Or` to make where condition properly. Please try code like given below.

```
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar";
$query_cond = "";

if($by_name !="") {
      $query_cond .= " name='$by_name'";
}
if($by_sex !="") {

      if(!empty($query_cond)){
          $query_cond .= " AND ";
       }

      $query_cond .= " sex='$by_sex'";
}

if($by_group !="") {

      if(!empty($query_cond)){
          $query_cond .= " AND ";
       }

      $query_cond .= " blood_group='$by_group'";
}

if($by_level !="") {

      if(!empty($query_cond)){
          $query_cond .= " OR ";
       }

      $query_cond .= " e_level='$by_level'";
 }

 if(!empty($query_cond)){
      $query_cond = " Where ".$query_cond;
      $search_query.$query_cond;
 }
```

Here in code First we take `$query_cond` variable empty and make condition according code. and manage `AND` operator according that. And in last if We found `$query_cond` not empty then add it to `$select_query`.

I hope it will be helpful for you.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
function search_donar($_POST) {

        $by_name = $_POST['by_name'];
        $by_sex = $_POST['by_sex'];
        $by_group = $_POST['by_group'];
        $by_level = $_POST['by_level'];

        $isfirst=0;
        $search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar WHERE";
        if($by_name !="") {

          $search_query .= " name='$by_name'";
          $isfirst=1;
        }
        if($by_sex !="") {
            if($isfirst!=0)
            $search_query .= " AND ";
          $search_query .= " sex='$by_sex'";
          $isfirst=1;
        }
        if($by_group !="") {
            if($isfirst!=0)
            $search_query .= " AND ";
          $search_query .= " blood_group='$by_group'";
          $isfirst=1;
        }
        if($by_level !="") {
            if($isfirst!=0)
            $search_query .= " AND ";
          $search_query .= " e_level='$by_level'";
          $isfirst=1;
        }
        $result = mysql_query($search_query);

        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this where you don't use validation, it is recomended not to use whether Field is EMPTY or NOT. Try below code, Hope it will work

```
function search_donar($_POST) {

    $by_name = $_POST['by_name'];
    $by_sex = $_POST['by_sex'];
    $by_group = $_POST['by_group'];
    $by_level = $_POST['by_level'];

    $search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar WHERE name LIKE '%$by_name%' AND sex LIKE '%$by_sex%' AND blood_group LIKE '%$by_group%' AND  e_level LIKE '%$by_level%' ";

    $result = mysql_query($search_query);

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function search_donar($_POST) {

    $by_name = $_POST['by_name'];
    $by_sex = $_POST['by_sex'];
    $by_group = $_POST['by_group'];
    $by_level = $_POST['by_level'];

    $search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar WHERE";

    $and = '';
    if(count($_POST) > 1) {
        $and ='AND';
    }
    if($_POST[0]) {
        $and ='';
    }

    if($by_name !="") {
        $search_query .= $and." name='$by_name'";
    }
    if($by_sex !="") {
        $search_query .= $and." sex='$by_sex'";
    }
    if($by_group !="") {
        $search_query .= $and." blood_group='$by_group'";
    }
    if($by_level !="") {
        $search_query .= $and." e_level='$by_level'";
    }

    if(count($_POST) == 0) {
        $search_query .= " 1 ";
    }

    $search_query;
    $result = mysql_query($search_query);

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do in this way.

```
function search_donar($_POST) {

    $by_name = $_POST['by_name'];
    $by_sex = $_POST['by_sex'];
    $by_group = $_POST['by_group'];
    $by_level = $_POST['by_level'];

    $search_query = "SELECT * FROM donar WHERE 1 = 1";
    if($by_name !="") {
      $search_query .= " AND name='$by_name'";
    }
    if($by_sex !="") {
      $search_query .= " AND sex='$by_sex'";
    }
    if($by_group !="") {
      $search_query .= " AND blood_group='$by_group'";
    }
    if($by_level !="") {
      $search_query .= " AND e_level='$by_level'";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($search_query);
    return $result;
}
```